# Is AWS Storage Gateway images accessible via URL?

Tags: aws-storage-gateway

For our gallery website, I uploaded our images to AWS S3 because they're available to the public (via URL). But, it's a 12-month trial, it's 5GB, and there's a limited amount of puts and gets. The 12-month trial isn't an issue, but the 5GB capacity and the limited GETs are.

So I noticed *AWS Storage Gateway*, that's 100 GB of supposedly *ALWAYS FREE* storage.

Are the images I load to *AWS Storage Gateway* accessible via URL? For example, if I upload image ***SunsetInMiami.jp*g**, will I be able to access it from the *outside* via a URL?